# JBPM users and roles disabled for admin user

Tags: jboss, jbpm

I am very new to jBPM and I have recently installed 7.15 version. The user and groups displays is empty in counter and when i select, the two tabs are disabled. Hence unable to add users or groups.

Any idea why this is happening? is there any configuration i might have missed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to http-remoting error in console. Default port and IP were getting used while installing. On fixing this error, the issue got resolved.